# List index out of range in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

All code

```
import random
import time

class Enemy():
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100
        self.power = random.randint(10,20)

    def hit(self, player):
        player.health -= self.power


class player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 300
        self.power = 50

    def hit(self, Enemy):
        Enemy.health -= self.power


player1 = player()
enemies = []
for i in range(5):  # create 5 enemy
    enemies.append(Enemy())
print("Play - Help - Quit")
action1 = input("Type 'hit' for enemies\n>>>> ")

while action1 != 'q':
    print("---------------")
    for i in range(len(enemies)):
        print("#{}.enemy heatlh-->{}".format(i, enemies[i].health))
    print("----------------")
    random_enemy = random.randint(1, 5)
    action = input(">>>> ")
    if action == 'hit':
        which = int(input("Which enemy? there are {} enemies\n>>>>".format(len(enemies))))
        if enemies[which].health == 0:
            enemies[which].health = 0
            print("\nThis is a death enemy")
        else:
            player1.hit(enemies[which])
            damage_enemy = random.randint(1,5)
            
            if enemies[random_enemy].health == 0:
                continue
            else:
                if damage_enemy == 1 or damage_enemy == 3 or damage_enemy == 4:
                    if enemies[which].health == 0 or enemies[which].health <= 0:
                        enemies[which].health = 0
                        print("{}. enemy death HP: {} ".format(which, enemies[which].health))
                    else:
                        enemies[random_enemy].hit(player1)
                        print("{}. enemy hit you {} damage, your HP: {} ".format(random_enemy,enemies[random_enemy].power,player1.health))


                elif enemies[which].health != 0 or enemies[which].health >= 0:
                    print("{}. enemy HP: {} ".format(which, enemies[which].health))
    elif action == 'q':
        break
```

I get this error at random time, my list size is 5, enemies die and their healths are 0. They stay there, but for some reason sometimes I get this error.

- #0.enemy heatlh-->100
- #1.enemy heatlh-->100
- #2.enemy heatlh-->0
- #3.enemy heatlh-->0
- #4.enemy heatlh-->100

```
if enemies[random_enemy].health == 0:
                continue
```

[image: When i select 3. enemy for hit, i got this error]

Comment: The `randint` function includes the upper limit integer as well. Try setting `random_enemy = random.randint(0, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

The `random.randint(1, 5)` can return 5. Your list has 5 elements, but the indices are from 0 to 4.

P.S. Also, the minimum value that you get is 1. Not 0.